# Trouble with forms

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I'm working on an assignment for school and I'm having trouble with forms. How do I space each box out correctly? I'm also not really sure how to change the style of the boxes so they're light grey and have rounded corners. I need it to look just like this sample. I've read lots of tutorials online and I still don't seem to get it.

[image: Text]

```
<div class="customer">
                    <h3>CUSTOMER INFORMATION</h3>
                    <p class="add">Add your address details below below</p>
                    <form action="search.html" method="get">
                        <p>
                          <label for="first">First Name</label>
                          <input class="first" name="first" type="first" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="last">Last Name</label>
                          <input class="last" name="last" type="last" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="street">Street Address</label>
                          <input class="street" name="street" type="street" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
                          <input class="apt" name="apt" type="apt" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="city">City</label>
                          <input class="city" name="city" type="city" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <label for="province">Province</label>
                            <input class="province" name="province" type="province"/>
                        <p>
                            <label for="postal">Postal Code</label>
                            <input class="postal" name="postal" type="postal" />
                            <p>
                                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                <input class="phone" name="phone" type="phone" />

                      </form>
                    <div class="continue">
                        <p class="continue_text">CONTINUE CHECKOUT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: if it works then consider green tick.

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a specific question and include what you’ve tried? Right now you’re asking to fully style an entire form, which is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @chrono where is your customer class defintion css??

Comment: @chorono my answer below is working you can give it a green tick!!! see below I have dessigned the whole thing for yoou!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have made both the input and label elements `display: block`

```css
input, label {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer">
                    <h3>CUSTOMER INFORMATION</h3>
                    <p class="add">Add your address details below below</p>
                    <form action="search.html" method="get">
                        <p>
                          <label for="first">First Name</label>
                          <input class="first" name="first" type="first" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="last">Last Name</label>
                          <input class="last" name="last" type="last" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="street">Street Address</label>
                          <input class="street" name="street" type="street" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
                          <input class="apt" name="apt" type="apt" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label for="city">City</label>
                          <input class="city" name="city" type="city" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <label for="province">Province</label>
                            <input class="province" name="province" type="province"/>
                        <p>
                            <label for="postal">Postal Code</label>
                            <input class="postal" name="postal" type="postal" />
                            <p>
                                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                <input class="phone" name="phone" type="phone" />

                      </form>
                    <div class="continue">
                        <p class="continue_text">CONTINUE CHECKOUT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It will shift label above input, this works then create all your styling afterwards

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        label {
            font-size: small;
            color: grey;
        }
        bkcolor{
            background-color: grey  ;
        }
        n {
            color: red;
        }

        .btn-primary {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #851f1f;
            border-color: #851f1f
        }

        .btn-primary:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #851f1f;
            border-color: #851f1f
        }

        .btn-primary.focus,
        .btn-primary:focus {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #851f1f;
            border-color: #851f1f;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(38, 143, 255, .5)
        }

        .btn-primary.disabled,
        .btn-primary:disabled {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #851f1f;
            border-color: #851f1f;
        }

        .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
        .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
        .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #851f1f;
            ;
            border-color: #851f1f;
        }

        .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
        .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
        .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(133, 31, 31, .5)
        }


.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color:rgb(233, 229, 229);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="customer">
            <h3 style="font-family: fantasy;">CUSTOMER INFORMATION</h3>
            <m class="add" style="font-family:cursive;">Add your address details below below</m>
            <form action="search.html" method="get">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div>
                            <label for="first">First Name<n>*</n></label>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <input class="form-control" name="first" type="first" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label for="last">Last Name<n>*</n></label>
                        <div >
                            <input class="form-control" name="last" type="last" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">

                        <label for="street">Street Address<n>*</n></label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="street" type="street" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="apt" type="apt" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-8">
                        <label for="city">City<n>*</n></label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="city" type="city" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">

                        <label for="province">Province<n>*</n></label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="province" type="province" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label for="postal">Postal Code<n>*</n></label>

                        <input class="form-control" name="postal" type="postal" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number<n>*</n></label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="phone" type="phone" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

            <br><br><br>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-5">Continue Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

check https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/7ad9Lbcn/

Comment: I would've given you a upvote, but you're using bootstrap which wasn't a requirement.

Comment: @RickardElimää that was a requirement my brother!!! otherwise it wouldnt had been made that fast and easy!!!!  :-)

Comment: For a school project where it's (probably) about learning CSS?

Comment: There is no `bootstrap` tag in OP question

Comment: @ahmed ali richard  why you guys are targeting me .If the rewuiremnet  is fulfilled by bootstrap why cant take that solution and moreover html css will be too lenghty .

Comment: There is no `bootstrap` tag in OP question, he only wants to achieve this using css not `bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

1) You're using the wrong semantics. `p` is for text; use `div` instead.

```
<div>
  <label for="street">Street Address</label>
  <input class="street" name="street" type="street" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
  <input class="apt" name="apt" type="apt" />
</div>
```

2) You need to add each input that are in separate rows in a row container.

```
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <label for="first">First Name</label>
    <input class="first" name="first" type="first" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="last">Last Name</label>
    <input class="last" name="last" type="last" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div>
    <label for="street">Street Address</label>
    <input class="street" name="street" type="street" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
    <input class="apt" name="apt" type="apt" />
  </div>
</div>
```

3) Use `display: flex` to control each row.

4) Use `display: block` to make each label be on a row on its own.

5) Use `0.5rem`, `1rem` and `2rem` as distances when you're using distances.

```css
.row {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.row > .column + .column { /* Target .column that follows a .column */
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.row > .column > label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <label for="first">First Name</label>
    <input class="first" name="first" type="first" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <label for="last">Last Name</label>
    <input class="last" name="last" type="last" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <label for="street">Street Address</label>
    <input class="street" name="street" type="street" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
    <input class="apt" name="apt" type="apt" />
  </div>
</div>
```

6) You're using classes wrong. Use `id` for unique elements, and use classes to group similar elements with CSS styles (ex. `.rows`, `.column` and `.grey`).

7) You can use multiple classes for an element (`.column` in this case).

8) `type` should be "text" for all inputs.

```css
.row {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.row > .column.full-size,
.row > .column.half
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.row > .column.small {
  max-width: 130px;
}

.row > .column + .column { /* Target a .column that follows another .column */
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.row > .column > label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"].grey {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* to count padding into width when in a flex element */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="half column">
    <label for="first">First Name</label>
    <input class="grey" name="first" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="half column">
    <label for="last">Last Name</label>
    <input class="grey" name="last" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="full-size column">
    <label for="street">Street Address</label>
    <input class="grey" name="street" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="small column">
    <label for="apt">Apt / unit / suit # </label>
    <input class="grey" name="apt" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

All this should get you going. Now it's only a matter of fact of filling in the rest of the styles to make it look like you want it to look like.